# parsing json gotten from fcm response on android onMessageReceived

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am pushing firebase cloud message notification from server and am getting this response in form of a json. am a little bit confused on how to parse the json. 
The response received is

```
{data={"title":"New Confirmation","message":"NGN 450 has been added to your wallet!"}}
```

I would like to access the title and the message.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
 remoteMessage.getData().get("title")
....
}
```

Comment: its not working...this is the json format am getting  {data={"title":"value","message":"value"}}. i think the "=" sign is improper

Comment: then try to first convert it to JSONObject like this, ```JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData())```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
    val data = message?.data ?: HashMap()
    if(data.containsKey("title")){
        Log.v("onMessageReceived", "" + data.get("title").toString())
    }

   if(data.containsKey("message")){
        Log.v("onMessageReceived", "" + data.get("message").toString())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have get notification response in `onMessageReceived` and you said that your notification response coming as JSON then try this.

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

      //Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
      //String title = data.get("title");
      //String message = data.get("message");


     JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
     String title = jsonObject.optString("title").toString();
     String message = jsonObject.optString("message").toString();
     // then pass your title and message to notification
}
```

Comment: this is not working for me...this is the json format {data={"title":"value","message":"value"}}..i tam not clear with the "=" sign on the json response

Comment: I've updated the answer, you can try this as you mention that your notification response as JSON.